# In "Ich möchte Frau Lohmann sprechen", Is Frau Lohmann the objective of sprechen? or suject of sprechen?

Tags: verb, infinitive, objects

My German textbook doesn't provide enough grammar explanation. Is the above sentence translate in English to "I want to speak to Frau Lohmann" or "I want Frau Lohmann to speak"?
When I look up 'sprechen' in the web dictionary, it says it is both vi. and vt. but doesn't show the usage so I don't know if it can be used like "sprechen jn" or "sprechen jm". What's the correct usage of the word?  (Explanation with posaible usagea will be deeply appreciated.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Ich möchte Frau Lohmann sprechen.

*I want to speak to Frau Lohmann.*

*Frau Lohmann* is an accusative object. The reason why this puzzles you is *sprechen* means both *to speak* and *to speak to someone (acc.)*. There is an also common alternative:

> Ich möchte **mit** Frau Lohmann sprechen.

*I want to speak to (AE: also with) Frau Lohmann.*

**Mit** is a preposition which takes dative. *Mit Frau Lohmann* is a prepositional object then.

In contrary,

> I want Frau Lohmann to speak.

has to be translated *Ich möchte, dass Frau Lohmann spricht.* In that case, the whole second clause is an *Objektsatz*, which replaces an accusative object required by the verb *möchte*.